# Slack, sending and receiving messages

Tags: php, bots, slack-api

I am new in slack and i would like to do a bot user in my channel.
The problem is: every time that i want to send a message to slack i have to refresh my page (the page that receives the information from slack).
I configured my Incoming Webhook with success.

This is what i did to configured my incoming webhook with success in php:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
    echo $entityBody;
```

My question is why do i have to refresh my page in order to receive or send messages to slack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your have the refresh your page is that it contains the PHP code ( I assume) and refreshing it triggers its execution. That is however not how you would usually do it. Depending on your use case you would usually have another web service trigger your script, e.g. a Slack event.

For implementing a bot user one approach is to use the [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) and subscribe to the [`message`](https://api.slack.com/events/message) event. Each time a message is send your script will automatically be called by Slack and can then process the incoming message.

For sending a message back will just require to simple reply to the Slack request with an `echo`. You would not need an incoming webhook for that.

Comment: I just added the event message. I had now have the scopes: channels:history, groups:history, im:history, mpim:history in my app. It doesn t work still. I keep having to refresh the page.

Comment: Cool. Make sure events are enabled in "Event Subscription" and the URL of your script is set as "Request URL" for events. If your web server is local, check out [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to get a secure public URL that will work with Slack.

Comment: Now is responding thanks. But is giving me an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, that can happen. You may want to only respond to messages events that do not come from your bot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of sending outgoing messages to slack with `curl`

```
<?php
define('SLACK_WEBHOOK', 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx/yyy/zzz');
function slack($txt) {
  $msg = array('text' => $txt);
  $c = curl_init(SLACK_WEBHOOK);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('payload' => json_encode($msg)));
  curl_exec($c);
  curl_close($c);
}
?>
```

Snippet taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/urigoren/be3190dd8a1d1d84994e1c066f2845b0)